# App.xaml can not found namespace IocContainter MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

I'm making a windows 10 universal application whit the MVVM patern. I'm placing this code into the App.xaml file:

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="WishLister.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WishLister"
    xmlns:services="using:WishLister.Services"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        
        <ResourceDictionary>        
            <services:IocContainer x:Key="ioc" /> <!--> error happens here -->

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates/Rescources.xaml" x:Name="recources"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
    
</Application>
```

But it give me this error on the marked line:

> The name `IocContainer` does not exist in the namespace `using:WishLister.Services`.

I've also try to use `clr-namespace:WishLister.Services` in stad of the italic code but I've got these two errors:

> The name `IocContainer` does not exist in the namespace `clr-namespace:WishLister.Services`.
>
> Unknown type `IocContainer` in XML namespace `clr-namespace:WishLister.Services;assembly=WishLister, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

But I have made a class `WishLister.Services.IocContainer`. Here is the code:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using WishLister.ViewModels;

namespace WishLister.Services
{
    public class IocContainer
    {
        public IocContainer Ioc
        {
            get
            {
                return App.Current.Resources["ioc"] as IocContainer;
            }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel MainPageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainPageViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public IocContainer()
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainPageViewModel>(false);
        }
    }
}
```

What's the problem whit this code?

Comment: Remove `<services:IocContainer x:Key="ioc" />` and anything that references the `services` xmlns.  Build your solution.  Fix anything preventing this.  Then clean, restart VS, and rebuild.  If all is well, try to add your IocContainer into the xaml again.  Also, if IocContainer isn't defined in the same assembly as WishLister.App you'll need to do some other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it by a comment of @Will. He or she sayed:

> 1. Remove `<services:IocContainer x:Key="ioc" />` and anything that references the services xmlns.
> 2. Build your solution.
> 3. Fix anything preventing this.
> 4. Then clean, restart Visual Studio, and rebuild.
> 5. If all is well, try to add your IocContainer into the xaml again.
>
> Also, if `IocContainer` isn't defined in the same assembly as `WishLister.App` you'll need to do some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean and Rebuild your project.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: I cannot write a comment because I don't have enough 50 reputations.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
xmlns:services="clr-namespace:WishLister.Services"
```

Comment: I'm sorry didn't work also. See my question to have more details. I've update it.

Comment: I have replicated your code and with "clr-namespace:WithLister.Services" compiles without problems... maybe your Services project is not compiling because an error? BTW..you should change your xmlns:local="using:WishLister" for xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WishLister"

Comment: Another thing..if Services is in another project of your solution, you should import it of course

Comment: I don't see how this doesn't provide an answer. It's because is too short, or because it does not explain why to change the problematic code for this one? I'm not trying to be mean, just want to learn. Thx